# VSTS feed "refresh" mechanism in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, azure-devops

I have set up a VSTS nuget feed. And I have pushed some packages two days ago. I was able to add those packages to my project. But I needed to push an other version for one of them. Made new nupgk version, pushed it and I can see it in VSTS, I can download it from there, Visual Studio 2017 is also listing it correctly but when I try to install it, I am getting an error:

> Package 'whatever 1.0.1' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'https://whatever.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/feedname/nuget/v3/index.json'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.         0

What I have tried:
- waiting around 10 minutes
- restarted Visual Studio several times
- pasting the above url into a browser and refreshing it manually several times

One or more of these helped. But I would like to know if there is any canonic solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the answer widget to have some formatting. Still, this might not be "the" answer, as I don't know the mechanism beyond. But it looks to be a workaround.

Steps:

1. Create a solution with a library project (let's call it L01)
2. Add another library project to the solution (let's call it D01)
3. Make a nuget package from L01 (version 0.0.1)
4. Push the package to your VSTS feed
5. Manage packages for project D01 and browse your feed
6. Package L01 v0.0.1 will be listed
7. Add it to project D01, it will work
8. Edit L01 nuspec file and change version to 0.0.2
9. Build and push the new package
10. Go back to project D01 and refresh the package list. The update will be shown.
11. Try to update. It will fail with the error message from my question.
12. Now go to folder `%localappdata%\NuGet\v3-cache` (or [equivalent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders))
13. Locate the folder corresponding to your feed and open it
14. Locate `list_l01.lib_index.dat` (where l01 is the package name) and delete it
15. Go back to project D01 and try to install the update. It will succeed.

Would be good if others could confirm. I have reproduced this several times.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to download the package or packages that where just freshly pushed to VSTS nuget feed.

Since Visual Studio 2017 is listing it correctly, then the issue should not related to the feed on VSTS server.

If this occurs very recently(download the new refresh package) and your package is very large, this maybe a network delay. Suggest you use a fiddler trace when this issue happens again. This makes "some" sense, what you see is probably an incorrect propagation of pushed packages showing up in the search results but not yet available to download.

And some other also encounter the same issue and error as you.

> FYI, I've been seeing this exact issue in the past month or so.
>   Switching between sources, uninstalling and reinstalling are some work
>   arounds, but not 100%. **Pushing my own packages up to VSTS and then
>   it takes like 15 minutes to finally get it to install.**
>
> [image]

More details please take a look at this similar issue [Package update not found when updating via Visual Studio Solution](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1827)

Comment: Yes, it looks to be a quite old problem :(
My package is small. And I can download it from VSTS web interface. This tells me, that it is strongly related to the client side. I am suspecting some caching problem, and I will try to prove this.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Any update feel free to post here, if it's related to nuget cache in VS2017, how to clean nuget related cache in VS2017, please take a look at this blog: [Clear All NuGet Cache VS 2017](http://codesteer.com/blog/clear-nuget-cache-vs-2017/)

Comment: See my post below. It is related to caching, but you don't need to clear all the cache.